# Multiprocessing with partial shared memory

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

I have a least sequre problem at hand: $Xw = Y$, where $X$ is my (training) *data* matrix and $w$ is a vector parametrizing my model. I already have a code that does it for me:

```py
def solve_lsqr(X,Y):
    # something standard
    return w
```

I want to perform a specific type of cross-validation, namely subsampling my data with a particular set of lags (as opposed to the shuffled subsampling approach of e.g. scikit-learn). So, instead of passing all my data to `solve_lsqr`, the function processes a subset  of the data that is selected in a particular manner.

I used python's multiprocessing to parallelize my code, but I believe my approach is suboptimal: *I pass the entire subsampled data array (not indices) to the function. This, once performed in parallel, fills my RAM completely and degrades the performance substantially.*

**I think it's more reasonable to just pass the index set to `solve_lsqr`, and somehow inform it of the location of data matrices $(X,Y)$**. This requires some sort of partial shared memory among all the workers in the `Pool` object of multiprocessing library. Partial, because other than $(X,Y)$, all internal variables of workers are essentially independent.

How can I implement that in python? Is it even possible to do that with the native multiprocessing library?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as declaring the data matrices $X,Y$ as `global` (read-only) variables inside `solve_lsqr` and passing the proper indices with python slices.